# Install new regex module with setup.py

Tags: python, regex, installation, setup.py

I'm trying to install the new Regex module

The readme.txt says:::

```
To build and install regex for your default Python run 

    python setup.py install

To install regex for a specific version run setup.py with that interpreter, e.g.

    python3.1 setup.py install
```

I type in `python setup.py install` and get back `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I'm looking for the answer but people keep referring me to the Python docs and they are confusing.

I know it is really simple but I'm just not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: You're sure you've moved to the correct directory in your terminal?

Comment: not sure.  how do i know? do i need to move the files into the framework folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicit first step in these instructions is to download a tarball or zip file of regex, unpack it, go into that directory, and there run “python setup.py install”.  See http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#the-new-standard-distutils

If you have pip installed, you can avoid these manual steps by running “pip install regex”.

Comment: i'm in the directory of the unzipped regex folder.  i then tried python setup.py install and got -bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python: No such file or directory

Comment: figured it out thank you.  it says i still have an error : running install_egg_info
Writing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/regex-2013_06_26-py2.7.egg-info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 52, in <module>
    setup.py
but i can still import regex

Comment: Further, you can explicitly set the current version. e.g. pip install regex==2017.4.29

Answer (score 1):

It's Easy (On Mac):

1. Install easy_install

   `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python`
2. Install pip

   `sudo easy_install pip`
3. Install regex module

   `pip install regex`

Answer (score 0):

On `Ubuntu` and `Python3.5`, I was having an issue where it wasn't compiling when I try to install `regex` with pip ( `pip install regex`) :

```
Building wheels for collected packages: regex
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for regex ... error
  Complete output from command /var/www/envs/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-i08laat0/regex/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-xlh43fe_ --python-tag cp35:
  /var/www/envs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:397: UserWarning: Normalizing '2018.02.21' to '2018.2.21'
    normalized_version,
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  copying regex_3/regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  copying regex_3/_regex_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  copying regex_3/test_regex.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  running build_ext
  building '_regex' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex_3
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/var/www/envs/include/python3.5m -c regex_3/_regex.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/regex_3/_regex.o
  regex_3/_regex.c:46:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for regex
  Running setup.py clean for regex
Failed to build regex
```

Solved that by installing `python3-dev` : `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`